# best way to allow concurrent sessions to windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-access

I need to allow 4 users to access remotely a machine with Windows Server 2012. Each user must authenticate and should be able to use one specific program.

What is the best way to achieve this scenario?

Is there an alternative to Remote Desktop?

Comment: Why would you want an alternative to Remote Desktop?

Comment: `Is there an alternative to Remote Desktop?` - No there isn't. Any solution that doesn't involve the proper roles and licenses is a violation of the EULA>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with only 2 of your 4 users being able to connect simultaneously, Remote Desktop in Remote Administration mode (the default) will work and you don't have to do anything except turn it on.

If you need the ability for all 4 users to be connected at the same time, full fledged (and licensed) Remote Desktop Services is pretty much your only option if the program your users need to run has a GUI. There are alternatives if the program is text-based.

Comment: Running applications from an administrative session is a violation of the EULA.

Comment: Really? I had no idea. How do they define "applications"?

Comment: If you're running applications such as those that you'd run from your workstation, like Office, LOB applications, etc. The two concurrent sessions are for administration of the system. Microsoft makes that very clear.

Comment: It seems like a pretty subjective distinction that would be largely impossible to enforce both legally and technically. That said, OP should obviously take the information into account when making a decision about how to proceed.

Comment: True, but that doesn't inviolate the EULA. It's up to each person/organization to make sure they follow the terms of the EULA for any system/software they're using.

Comment: It's not a Microsoft app, it's an application which allows connections from multiple clients. The problem is that the client requires a shared folder to function properly but the users need to work out of the office.

Comment: I don't understand why the users are establishing RDP sessions to the server then. Any use of the two default RDP sessions for anything other than administration of the server is a violation of the EULA. I've stated this multiple times. I can't be any more clear on this point.

Comment: @user1498339 Does your program even need RDP at all? If all you need is shared folders, you can do that over a VPN.